# How can I remove vendor.php from URL?

Tags: php

My Current URL is (localhost/dumps/vendor.php/microsoft-question-answers) How can I remove vendor.php from URL ?

Comment: Use htaccess redirection rule to formate your URL

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^dumps/vendor.php/microsoft-question-answers(.*)$ http://localhost/dumps/microsoft-question-answers$1 [r=301,nc]
```